Android Load latest SMS conversations crashed on android 14
I am using below code to fetch latest Sms message group by thread_id and address.
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[]{THREAD_ID, ADDRESS, "MAX(date) AS date", BODY, "sum(read = 0) AS msg_count"};
    String  selection = ADDRESS + " != '2525')) Group By (" + ADDRESS + "," + THREAD_ID;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{};
    Cursor c =  cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
            projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, DATE + " DESC"
    );

All things is ok in android devices with smaller than 14,
It seems some conditions will be added to my query by android 14 and app crashed!!!!
Error is :
SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:
SELECT thread_id, address, MAX(date) AS date, body, sum(read = 0) AS msg_count FROM sms 
WHERE ((address != '2525')) Group By (address,thread_id) 
AND (sub_id IN ('1','-1') OR address IN ('911','112'))) ORDER BY date DESC

Why this condition is added to the query ??
AND (sub_id IN ('1','-1') OR address IN ('911','112'))) 

